# how does navGraph viewModel work under the hood?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, android-architecture-navigation

so my question is pretty straight forward. viewmodel needs a scope to stay alive. such as activity or fragment. so I guess there must be a class associated with the `navgraph` that survives through multiple fragments.so how is that implemented?

```
val viewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.my_nav_graph).
```

Comment: Note that the source code for all of this is available. For example, [this file](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:navigation/navigation-fragment-ktx/src/main/java/androidx/navigation/NavGraphViewModelLazy.kt?q=navGraphViewModels) has `navGraphViewModels`.

Comment: yeah thank you, its a little hard to follow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [Reference a destination using NavBackStackEntry documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#navbackstackentry):

> Starting with Navigation 2.2.0, you can get a reference to the [`NavBackStackEntry`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavBackStackEntry) for any destination on the navigation stack by calling [`NavController.getBackStackEntry()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#getBackStackEntry(int)), passing it a destination ID.

> The returned `NavBackStackEntry` provides a `Lifecycle`, **`a ViewModelStore`**, and a SavedStateRegistry at the destination level. These objects are valid for the lifetime of the destination on the back stack. When the associated destination is popped off the back stack, the Lifecycle is destroyed, the state is no longer saved, and any ViewModel objects are cleared.

So when you call `by navGraphViewModels()`, it is the `NavBackStackEntry` for that navigation graph that is used. As that `NavBackStackEntry` remains on the back stack while you're on any of the destination within that graph, that same `NavBackStackEntry` is returned no matter what destination in that graph you call `by navGraphViewModel()` on, ensuring that those multiple fragments all have a shared scope. Once you pop all of the fragments off the back stack, the navigation graph and its `NavBackStackEntry` are also popped, clearing out that shared state.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand. the documentation says "you can get a reference to the NavBackStackEntry for any destination on the navigation stack by calling NavController.getBackStackEntry(), passing it a destination ID".  what I understand from that is every destination must have a different `NavBackStackEntry`. but you are saying that it belongs to the navigation graph and holds the ViewModel and you always get the same instance.

Comment: the documentation even demonstrates that if there are several instances of the destination in the back stack, calling  `getBackStackEntry()` will return the topmost `NavBackStackEntry`. I'm confused

Comment: That's why you pass in an ID to `by navGraphViewModels()` - specifically **the ID of a `<navigation>` destination.** **That** is what gives you the `NavBackStackEntry` associated with the whole `<navigation>` graph and not the `NavBackStackEntry` associated with a single `<fragment>` destination within that graph. You could certainly pass the ID of an individual `<fragment>` destination to `by navGraphViewModels()`, but there's really no reason to do that vs just using Fragment's `by viewModels()` since they're both scoped to just that individual fragment.

Comment: so basically a viewModel that belongs to a fragment survives until that fragment pops out of the back stack, right? and a ViewModel that belongs to a navGraph survives until all fragments from that nav graph pops out?  and what I'm really curious about is how is that navGraph's  `NavBackStackEntry` is implemented to survive?!! what holds its reference?

Comment: Yes, you're correct on your thinking of when each scope is cleared. `getBackStackEntry()` is a method on `NavController` because it is the `NavController` that keeps references to all of the entries on the back stack.